# TIdSync Type name expected on indy 10.5.5

Tags: indy10

I am trying to create a class derived from TIdSync, but the compiler says Type Name Expected. Is that the version I use does not support TIdSync class?.

I am using RAD 2010 indy 10.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Delphi, add `IdSync` to your `uses` clause.

If you are using C++, add `#include <IdSync.hpp>` to your code.